# Grepping the output of find

Tags: grep, find

I am looking for a folder, but there are a lot of `Permission denied` messages. I want to filter these out by grepping the output. I tried this, informed by other questions:

`find / -type d -name 'force_fields' | xargs grep 'force_fields'`

However, I still get a flow of entries with `Permission denied` messages, making it impossible for me to filter out what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Would silencing the error stream be a solution?

```
find / -type d -name 'force_fields' 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

The errors are printed to `stderr`, but the results are printed to `stdout`. You can redirect the errors so you won't see them, like this:

```
find / -type d -name 'force_fields' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: 3 instant answers, all at the same time.. =)

Answer (score 3):

Those message are write trough the stadnard error channel (number 2). You can redirect the error message to `/dev/null` to avoid them by:

```
find / -type d -name 'force_fields' 2>/dev/null
```